# Is it posible to select a stack of value by using MYSQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I got a query like this :

```
SELECT email
FROM abc_table
GROUP BY email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
```

So it will return me :

```
email   
a@b.com     
c@d.com     
e@f.com
```

And now i need to adjust the query to get something like this :

```
email       id
a@b.com     1
a@b.com     2   
c@d.com     3
c@d.com     4
c@d.com     5
e@f.com     6
```

Is it posible to get this result by using GROUP BY HAVING ? Or any suggestion to get this result?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you have one more row with `(e@f.com, 7)` somewhere ?

Comment: Without knowing what's in your table, the samples are meaningless. It looks like you want to _remove_ the `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.email
     , a.id
FROM abc_table a
  JOIN
    ( SELECT email
      FROM abc_table
      GROUP BY email
      HAVING COUNT(email) > 1 
    ) AS ag
    ON ag.email = a.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM abc_table GROUP BY email
```

(EDIT: misread the question)